# How can I edit the css of an django form error message`?

Tags: python, django, file-upload, django-forms

I have a form on my Django app, which should allow users upload only `csv files` and whenever a user uplaods a file with a different extension, I want to render an error message. Currently I check the extention of the file which is uploaded and if the extension is not `.csv`  then I add an error in the `ValidationErrors`

The problem is that I can not find a way to edit the css of that error. Right now it is being displayed as an element of a list but I would like to put it in h1 tags. Here is my code:

forms.py

```
from django import forms
from .models import CSVUpload
import time

class CsvForm(forms.ModelForm):

    csv_file = forms.FileField(widget=forms.FileInput(
        attrs= {
            'class': 'form-group',
        }
    ))

    class Meta:
        model = CSVUpload
        fields = ('csv_file', )

    def save(self):
        csvfile = super(CsvForm, self).save()
        return csvfile


    def clean_csv_file(self):
       uploaded_csv_file = self.cleaned_data['csv_file']
       if uploaded_csv_file:
         filename = uploaded_csv_file.name
         if filename.endswith('.csv'):
             return uploaded_csv_file 
         else:
             raise forms.ValidationError("File must be csv")
       else:
        return uploaded_csv_file
```

template

```
{% extends "fileconverter/base.html" %}

{% block content  %}

<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.csv_file }}
    {{ form.csv_file.errors }}

    <button type="submit" class="uploadbutton">Convert CSV</button>
</form>

{% endblock %}
```

Could someone help me understand how I could fix this? I appreciate any help you can provide

Comment: is there is any views.py file, please share that file too.

Comment: `h1` tags seem very semantically wrong here. If you just want larger text then use css... You can use css to style the list elements to look like "h1" elements as well (no need to change the content).

Answer (score 1):

You could change this by using a [custom errorlist class](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/forms/api/#how-errors-are-displayed).

But as others have said, this is almost certainly the wrong thing to do. Forms are not headers, so this is semantically incorrect. Instead, use CSS to style your errors in the way you want, including adding a custom `error_css_class` to the form as Alex demonstrates.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to specify the name of the css class in your component:

```
class CsvForm(forms.ModelForm):
    error_css_class = 'my_error_class'
....
```

Comment: this doesnt work unless you render the form as paragraph